# Examples of Riccati equations in physics

Tags: differential-equations, applied-physics

I am looking for a Riccati equation

$$y'(x)=a(x)+b(x)y(x)+c(x)y^2(x),$$

where $a(x),b(x)$ and $c(x)\neq 0$ in **physics that is solvable** (by easy methods). It would be great if at least one coefficient function would be non-constant so that it is not separable.

**EDIT:** Maybe my question was not clear enough. Are there any real problems in physics which lead to a Riccati equation? Or are Riccati equations only of theoretical interest in physics?

Comment: This post (v2) seems to be a list question.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Qmechanic means that this appears to be a question without "correct" answer, as it is looking for a potentially unbounded list of examples. Such questions are off-topic as *too broad*, in particular as they tend to not involve any *actual question about physics*.

Comment: This question is related to physics, as I want to know if there is any real application in physics in which a Riccati-Equations needs to be solved. Or are Riccati-Equations just interessting because of theoretical considerations?

Comment: The answer is "yes",  all over the place, *of course*; but you seem to want a list to your liking.  Why don't you do some google searching yourself? In any case, [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0110066) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6147). But answerers are reluctant to play "bring me another stone!".

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/8832/2451

Comment: This might interest you: - J. W. L. Glaisher, [On Riccati's equation and its transformations, and on some definite integrals which satisfy them](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1881.0018), Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London, Vol. 172 (1881), pp. 759-828.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first this that comes to my mind is the time dependent logistic equation with production:

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=r(t)N(t)\bigg(1-\frac{N(t)}{K(t)}\bigg) + A(t)$$

which arises in population dynamics describing the time evolution of a population (animals, cells, etc). The coefficient $r(t)$ represents the growth rate, while $K(t)$ is the carrying capacity, i.e. the maximum number of individuals the population can attain. In addition there is a source term $A(t)$ accounting for migration, for example. Notice that I wrote all the coefficients explicitly time-dependent, as you want to do it with non-constant coefficients. This equation can be written as:

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=A(t) + r(t)N - \frac{r(t)}{K(t)}N^2$$

which is a Riccati equation. The coefficients could be for example periodic, accounting for seasonal oscillations in breeding, etc.

For physics related examples, look up to this paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0110066.pdf